# Validating objects deserialized using DataContract

Tags: c#, validation, datacontract

I am writing a class which represents a mesh; a list of vertices and a list of indices into that list.  This class is immutable and is validated on construction.  However, I would also like to enforce validation on deserialization, such as receiving a mesh over WCF or reading it from a file.  I was using [OnDeserialized] to call the same validation method and throw a SerializationException if it failed, but on running unit tests on Mono on OS X, it wraps the SerializationException in a TargetInvocationException, which is not picked up by the ExpectedException attribute and as such, the test fails.

It might be a bug in Mono, but it got me wondering, am I doing this right in the first place?  What is the preferred way of doing this?

Validating in properties is not going to work as either property is reliant on the other for validation; ensuring indices are in range and triangles are not degenerate and so on.

Thank you.